# how to put value of array into checkbox in angular js

Tags: angularjs

I have response from my API in an array which looks like this 
["email","email"].
I want to use the data to map to values in a checkbox so that I could use the value to send email to selected checkbox contacts.

How can I tackle this?

```js
if($stateParams.nonExists){
  console.log($stateParams.nonExists)
  $scope.nonExists = $stateParams.nonExists
 }
 if($stateParams.data){
  return $q(function(resolve,reject){
   $http.get('/google/contacts?code='+$stateParams.data).
   success(function(res){
    if(res && res.length){
     resolve(res)
     console.log(res);
    }

  })
  })
  .then(function(emails){
   $http.post('/user/import/exists',{emails:_.pluck(emails,'address')}).
   success(function(data){
    $scope.existUsers = data.data.exists
    $scope.nonExists = data.data.nonExists
   })
  })
 }
```

This is the code in my controller. My problem is the data from the http request is in array like ['john@gmail.com, janedoe@gmail.com]
and I want to use those array values into checkbox to send emails to them

Comment: angular views are just a reflection of your model, so, just update the model...

Comment: I have it in my Scope variable but since it is just values i am having problem using it as my model.

Comment: Can you provide us your code, and explain a bit more what you exactly want? :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You must change data structure in current You don't know which email is on or off for sending. My proposition for structure is:

```
[
{"email":"email","send":false},
{"email":"email","send":true},
//...other emails
]
```

You can of course change structure in JavaScript if it cannot be done on servers side. How to set this structure to view with checkboxes - check working example:

```js
var app=new angular.module("checkbox",[]);

app.controller("main",function($scope){

   //example data
   var data=[
   "test1@email.com",
   "test2@email.com",
   "test3@email.com"
   
   ];

   $scope.checkboxes=[];//create new structure


   //convert to new structure
   for (var i=0; i<data.length; i++){

      $scope.checkboxes.push({email:data[i],send:false});//we add elements to new structure
   }
  
  
    //function is only for showing send property change
    $scope.showChange=function(element){

       console.log("You changed: "+element.email);

    };


    //function is doing conversion to previous structure
    $scope.getMailsForSend=function(){
       
        var emails=[];

        for (var i=0; i<$scope.checkboxes.length; i++){
              
            if ($scope.checkboxes[i].send)
            emails.push( $scope.checkboxes[i].email );//add only mails with send on true         
 
        }

        console.log("Your checked email adresses:");
        console.log(emails);

        return emails;
    };
  
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
<div ng-app="checkbox">

  <div ng-controller="main">
  <div ng-repeat="check in checkboxes">
  {{check.email}}<input type="checkbox" ng-change="showChange(check)" ng-model="check.send">
  </div>
  <button ng-click="getMailsForSend()">Give checked email adresses</button>
  </div>

  
</div>
```

So we set as `ng-model` of checkbox `send` object property and it is binded on  beginning and every change of checkbox state changes our `send` property.

Comment: could you please take a look now I added a portion of my code.

Comment: @SajakUpadhyaya I updated code with conversion from orginal structure.

Comment: @SajakUpadhyaya i added function to convert backward - check results on button click. Function gives only set emails.

Comment: I am sorry I was out on a vacation !! This helped thank you so much.